# i can't connect css file to html file at node.js server

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

I am building a Chat App with Express , Node.js and socket.io.

I tried linked my css file *chat.css* to html file *index.html* without success for 3 days.

*index.js*

[image]

*index.html*

[image]

Comment: Where is the `app.get('/assets/chat.css', function() {....});` statement into the index.js file?

Comment: Questions seeking help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary** to reproduce it **in the question itself**. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: And note, "code-as-images" is not good enough, and if anything is unclear, have a 2nd look at [ask].

Comment: Every resource coming from your server should be configured as an endpoint from the back-end side.

Comment: Ele I don't understand your answer, you can be more detailed?

Answer (score 1):

**This is what happens (high-level explanation)**

1. The browser makes a request to load the HTML file `index.html`.
2. Then, the browser will execute some tasks, one of them is loading resources like js, CSS, etc.
3. The HTML has a resource located on `assets/chat.css`, that path name belongs to the current domain, so, the browser makes a request, for example, `http://domain/assets/chat.css`.
4. The server-side receives that request, however, the express application doesn't have any configured endpoint called `/assets/chat.css` and probably you're receiving HTTP code `404` Not found.

**A solution could be adding the following into the index.js file**

```
app.get('/assets/chat.css', function() {
  //set headers to the response.
  // Of course, you know where the chat.css file is stored, this is an example
  res.sendFile(parent_folder + '/public/css/chat.css');
});
```